# Authenticate Azure AD Device With WiFi - RADIUS

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was reaching out in hope to figure out the best route for authenticating azure ad devices with wifi. Customer of mine currently has enterprise wifi that uses certs and radius servers. They have a test AAD device with all the certs required and wifi profile but fails to authenticate because the radius server can’t find the AAD device account in AD.

Do you guys know what Microsoft recommends for wifi authentication for azure ad devices?

We found the following 2 links that are a bit dated talking about setting up an extension for radius servers and azure ad.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6293/radius-and-azure-ad.html

Also found a more recent link discussing the same issue but the azure ad tech postedL

*Thanks for the feedback, we’re currently reviewing this capability to see how we can support RADIUS auth on NPS specifically, for AAD Joined Windows 10 devices to authenticate to WiFi access points.*
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/8816272-authenticating-wireless-access-points-radius-thr

Comment: Is this a programming question or a professional sysadmin question?  Sysadmin questions should be asked at https://serverfault.com/.  If a programming question, might you please [edit] your question to share a simplified version of your current code and showing where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no support for this.
This feature is in our back log and is in consideration for FY21H2.
This is tracked by this epic
Epic 1066701: As an IT admin, I can enable RADIUS based WiFi auth for AAD joined devices on on-prem NPS server (within the Azure Identity ADO).

A similar thread is here. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f1a190f-799d-4eef-8b12-41464a2e1240/scep-certificate-and-nps-auth?forum=microsoftintuneprod

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've found about the AzureAD extension for NPS says that it is for requiring a 2nd factor (provided by AzureAD MFA) to authenticate, and it still requires Active Directory to handle authentication of the 1st factor.  For the use case of authenticating AzureAD Joined devices connecting to the network, that's not helpful.

This seems to be something many AzureAD users have been requesting for a while now, but as yet it's not offered.  It sounds like Anup Reghunathan has some insight into this, perhaps he could provide an update?

For anyone else who comes across this thread, I'll share some options that I've come across in my search for a solution.  Radius-as-a-service.com and cloudradius.com both offer a cloud-based RADIUS service capable of authenticating against AzureAD.  I've also seen Jumpcloud mentioned, but from what I can tell their offering is a competing cloud-based directory service that happens to also provide radius, as opposed to a radius service designed to work with AzureAD. Lastly, I saw one person raving about Aruba Clearpass Policy Manager, offered as an on-prem appliance.  I don't have firsthand experience with any of the above though, so can't make any recommendation.

I also came across [this](https://sysmansquad.com/2021/04/27/working-around-nps-limitations-for-aadj-windows-devices/) workaround to make NPS authenticate AzureAD computers. It involves creating dummy computer accounts in on-prem AD and associating the certificates issued to the AzureAD Joined computers with the dummy accounts.  It looks like the author has automated the process to make things fairly simple, but I am hesitant to use an unsupported workaround like this when it comes to something so critical as authenticating wireless network connections.  It may be what I end up going with though, if we don't get a supported offering from MS soon.

Comment: Hi,
because I am in the same situation... dummy objects in AD will only work for a short time. MS changed requirements so that this won't be possible anymore.
Nevertheless, the only thing I was able to do is the user and not the client WIFI authentication.